# How to fire event mouseenter on grid header Extjs 6

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-architect, extjs6, extjs6-classic

I need fire event onMouseEnter in grid panel headers. But there is no such native event. Would have a solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a listeners like this:

```
listeners: {
    mouseenter: {
        element: 'el',
        delegate: '.x-column-header',
        fn: function(e){
            console.log(e.target)
        }
    }
}
```

Working example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1ofq

Comment: delegate: '.x-column-header', Is capturing all the divs, as it does to catch only the first div?

Comment: As [documented](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.0.2/classic/Ext.mixin.Observable.html#method-on) `delegate` is a simple selector to filter the target or look for a descendant of the target.

Comment: I solved this: if(el.getAttribute('role') == 'columnheader'). Tanks